# How do I pass a variable into html assigned to an element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('#player-container').html('<div id="film-player" class="flowplayer play-button is-splash"  style="background:#777 url(myVariable) no-repeat;">');
```

The html isn't showing up because it doesn't in code blocks here. Basically I'm trying to nest a variable like this: style equals background url(myVariable) in the html I'm assigning to the element dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you started the string with single quotes you use `'` again and `+` to concatenate like this:
`url(' + myVariable + ')`.

So your code should be:

```
$('#player-container').html('<div id="film-player" class="flowplayer play-button is-splash"   style="background:#777 url('+myVariable+') no-repeat;">');
```

More info about concatenation operator (in javascript) at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

Comment: Thanks, I was just doing that on my own while you answered, works great!

Comment: @Wendy, great! Maybe you can click to accept the answer anyway ;)

Comment: Oops, I thought I did! Voted it up instead, that's what happens when you're clicking too fast...